# try to scroll down the page , but it didnt work. selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_window_size(1366,768)
browser.get('https://www.google.ie/trends/explore#q=boston%20celtics')
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

I try to scroll down the page , but it didnt work. if anybody can help me .

Comment: While this wont solve your overall problem, you likely need to do some sort of wait between the `get` and `execute_script` method calls. That particular page "finishes" loading, but the actual content is still being AJAXed in. I would add an explicit wait for the loading spinner to no longer be displayed. Your `execute_script` call is what I normally use to scroll, and I'm curious why it doesn't work on this particular page.

Comment: Why are you trying to scroll down the page? If there is an element down the page that you want to interact with, interact with it and the browser will be scrolled for you.

Comment: @JeffC because I am try to click a botton of the page. if I dont scroll down, then element.click() has error information.

Comment: @LeviNoecker you are right. instead, I scroll to a element. and it works.   rising_botton=browser.find_element_by_id('searchBandTabControlRisingButtont0')
browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", rising_botton)

Comment: Are you use time sleep?